# please help! run example of ipc-bridge and error

Tags: ros, matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the example_publisher.m, the function 'geometry_msgs_Twist' cannot be recognized shown as below

```
Undefined function 'geometry_msgs_Twist' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in example_subscriber (line 12) pid=geometry_msgs_Twist('connect','subscriber','example_module','twist');
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224643/please-help!-run-example-of-ipc-bridge-and-error/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2016-01-20**:
maybe plot full error logs for us to understand your issues. It seems like **function declare** problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use the ipc_bridge functions, you must first add the path of the specific binary to Matlab:
addpath('Address to the /bin directory of specific message which includes all the mex-compiled binary files')

---

Originally posted by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) with karma: 108 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0